# Set the appropriate language_in option

Tags: javascript, maven

I have been using com.samaxes.maven minify maven plugin of version 1.7 to minify my js files. when i m trying to build my app. I am getting the error- ERROR: Parse Error. IE8(and below) will parse trailing commas in array and object literals incorrectly. I f you are targeting newer versions of JS, set the appropriate language_in option.

My maven plugin config is as follwos.

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>com.samaxes.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>minify-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-minify</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>                      
                    <configuration>
                        <jsEngine>closure</jsEngine>    
                        <language_in>ECMASCRIPT5</language_in>                          
                        <cssSourceFiles>                               
                        </cssSourceFiles>                           
                        <jsSourceFiles>
                              <!--  jquery -->
                             <jsSourceFile>core/jquery/1.8.2/jquery-1.8.2.js</jsSourceFile>
                             <jsSourceFile>core/jquery-ui/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js</jsSourceFile>
                             <!--  App -->
                             <jsSourceFile>app-src/app/App.js</jsSourceFile>
                             <!--Date utility-->
                             <jsSourceFile>core/xdate/xdate.js</jsSourceFile>                           
                             <jsSourceFile>app-src/tg/util/Utility.js</jsSourceFile>
                             <jsSourceFile>core/CharCounter.js</jsSourceFile>
                             <!-- Choosen-->
                             <jsSourceFile>core/chosen/chosen.jquery.js</jsSourceFile>
                             <jsSourceFile>core/jquery.uniform.js</jsSourceFile>    

                          </jsSourceFiles>
                          <jsFinalFile>appjs-all.js</jsFinalFile>
                          <linebreak>-1</linebreak>
                          <nomunge>false</nomunge>
                          <verbose>false</verbose>
                          <preserveAllSemiColons>false</preserveAllSemiColons>
                          <disableOptimizations>false</disableOptimizations>
                          <bufferSize>4096</bufferSize>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>minify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I have even used language_in as ECMASCRIPT5. but Unable to figure out the reason why i am getting the error.

Thank You All.

Comment: Please tag with maven also, so that u will get response from them too...

Comment: Still facing the same problem buddies..

Answer (score 2):

Using Closure, change your "language_in" definition by "closureLanguage".

For example:

```
 <plugin>
  <groupId>com.samaxes.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>minify-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.4</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>default-minify</id>
      <configuration>
        ...
        <jsEngine>CLOSURE</jsEngine>
        <closureLanguage>ECMASCRIPT5</closureLanguage>   <--- correct way
        ...
      </configuration>
      <goals>
        <goal>minify</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Changing the CLOSURE to YUI. which is default value. Worked for me. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain the "language_in" option is specific to the closure jsEngine. Changing it to 'yui' worked for me.

Also, here's a list of available options for this plug-in: http://samaxes.github.io/minify-maven-plugin/minify-mojo.html